# Making a recommendation based on the rating and location

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is my current recommendation code that I am using in my website. I would like to change it so that it recommends based on the hotel's location. If a user rated something (in this case a hotel in my website) it will recommend everything that I have in my website, but in the order from the highest rated hotel to the lowest. However, I would like to implement something that would recommend to the user the hotels that are based on the location of whatever hotel they rated. For instance, if they rated a hotel in Durham, it would output all the hotels that are in Durham...

SQL query:

```
$query = 'SELECT users.name as username, hotel.Hotel_name, tbl_rating.rate 
          FROM users
          JOIN tbl_rating ON users.id = tbl_rating.user_id
          JOIN hotel ON hotel.id = tbl_rating.hotel_id';
```

How can I modify the select statement to recommend based on the hotels location

DB for hotel structure:

```
id(int 11) 
Hotel_name(text)
Hotel_Location(text)
Hotel_price(int 11) 
image(varchar 500) 
description(text)
```

DB for rating structure:

```
id(int 11) 
rate(float) 
user_id(int 11)
hotel_id(int 11)
time_date(datetime)
```

Comment: and what do you expect from us now? Is there anything that you coded, which doesn't work?

Comment: I did try it but i deleted the code by mistake and i can't retrieve it now. I'm very stuck

Comment: If the question is that you're getting presented with too many rows in the output and you only want to see the ones that are relevant to a certain city (for example, as you say, `Durham`), then by the looks of the query, the change that would need to be made is: `$query = 'SELECT  users.name as username, hotel.Hotel_name, tbl_rating.rate FROM users JOIN tbl_rating ON users.id=tbl_rating.user_id JOIN hotel ON hotel.id = tbl_rating.hotel_id AND hotel_location = "Durham"'`;

Comment: I just gave an example as to durham... However, i have a lot of hotels in different locations. Would i need to list all of the locations?

Comment: Well, I guess, the question would then be, how do you determine the location that you want to present the data for?

Comment: The full code block was appropriately deleted by ahmed (but can be accessed by anyone by clicking the edit history link).  This question can be solved without the full code block, so do not bring it back.  For anyone who wants to help, it is a matter of adding a WHERE condition.

Comment: My question is, is it possible if a user rates a hotel and then the website recommends hotel's based  on the location,  the user rated initially rated. Would that be possible to implement?

Comment: @mickmackusa can you not help since you suggested its a matter of a Where condition please?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time to give a good quality, considered answer that is worthy of an SO answer.  (Easter weekend with family -- I am only sneeking a little SO time while family is in the shower)  Keep reading/researching it is okay for you to continue to self-solve.  p.s. while you are waiting for help, read about _table aliases_ and how they can simplify your sql statements.